# Vuetify Image load failed - Loading Google Thumbnails

Tags: google-drive-api, vuetify.js

I had a similar problem before with local image assets that I loaded. That issue was solved as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52105162/vuetify-standard-setup-babel-eslint-image-failed-to-load).

Now I have a similar issue but instead when loading images from the web, more precise when trying to load google thumbnail images.

I get the following error message in the console:

```
[Vuetify] Image load failed

 src: https://example.com/WZc5zlE...

 found in
 ...
```

The status code from the HTTPS request is 403 (forbidden):

[image]
However, if I copy the url from the error message to another tab in the browser the image load fine. Could it have something to do with referrer?

The error also comes and goes, sometimes it work fine to load them, sometimes not. Typically if I have loaded the image manually in browser tab, that specific image load well on my page as well next time.

My implementation:

```
<template>
  <v-img v-bind:src="getThumbNailSource()" max-height="100px" max-width="100px" contain></v-img>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
  data() {
    return {
      url: "https://example.com/WZc5zlE..."
    };
  },
   methods: {
      getThumbNailSource() {
         return `${this.url}`;
      }
   }
};
</script>
```

Google Drive Scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

Browser: Chrome (got the same behaviour in firefox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the referrerpolicy="no-referrer" helped.

```
   <img
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
      v-bind:src="getThumbNailSource()"
      max-height="100px"
      max-width="100px"
      contain
    />
```